# SQL Server Backups

Tags: sql-server, database-backups

I am having some issues with database backups.

My database is in simple recovery mode and database backup occurs every night. We some times getting backup job failed and throwing the error as below.

ERROR:

> The operating system returned the error '112(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105) while attempting 'SetEndOfFile' on \backups\sqlbackups\finename
>
> Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.
>
> Problems with the query / Property not set correctly / Parameters not set correctly:  this is running from past 2 years.

I am still unsure why this happens some times.

If anyone having the same issue and figured out the possible reason, please discuss

- Server info: SQL Server 2008 R2, Standard
- Database info: simple recovery mode and is acting as a publisher with size 1.4TB

Thanks in advance

Comment: System error 112 ERROR_DISK_FULL = There is not enough space on the disk.

Comment: Oh Ya... Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

It seems you haven't enough space on your destination place. Make sure that there is enough free space on your drive and try again. If you use a third-party tool to backup your databases set "Auto-delete" option to delete your old backups.